# 2.4 GHz, 5.0 GHz, Will Xbox only connect if they have different SSIDs?

Tags: router, ssid

Will an Xbox only connect to a wireless router if the 2.4 GHz signal and the 5.0 GHz signal have different SSIDs? Originally, I had it worked out where the 2.4 and the 5.0 GHz were coming off the same SSID, but today it stopped unexpectedly (no changes to any configurations or anything). I made it so that they both had different SSIDs and it worked fine. Can I make it so that they have the same SSID again, or will it not work anymore?

Comment: While this question is off-topic, in my experience I always keep the SSID names different.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same SSID and It works fine. I have an arrangement with a repeater to boost signal to the end of the yard, where the manufacturer's er repeater only supports 2.4 and I want to be able to work in in the hose and those areas without losing connection or switch SSID.

When you changed the SSID it probably rebooted the connection / router to apply the settings and its most likely that this is all that was needed.

Comment: I had already tried rebooting the modem and the router several times.